# Problem installing Devel::REPL using cpanm

Tags: perl

I tried following the instructions for installing CPAN modules at this link:

http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

However, when I try to install Devel::REPL, it fails.

Here is the log:

```
[user@machine] cpanm Devel::REPL
--> Working on Devel::REPL
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Devel-REPL-1.003025.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Module::Build::Tiny
--> Working on Module::Build::Tiny
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/Module-Build-Tiny-0.036.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: TAP::Harness::Env, ExtUtils::Helpers, ExtUtils::InstallPaths, ExtUtils::Config
--> Working on TAP::Harness::Env
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/Test-Harness-3.30.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Harness-3.30 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Harness-3.30 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Harness-3.30
--> Working on ExtUtils::Helpers
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/ExtUtils-Helpers-0.022.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ExtUtils-Helpers-0.022 ... OK
Building and testing ExtUtils-Helpers-0.022 ... OK
Successfully installed ExtUtils-Helpers-0.022
--> Working on ExtUtils::InstallPaths
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/ExtUtils-InstallPaths-0.010.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ExtUtils-InstallPaths-0.010 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: ExtUtils::Config
--> Working on ExtUtils::Config
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/ExtUtils-Config-0.007.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ExtUtils-Config-0.007 ... OK
Building and testing ExtUtils-Config-0.007 ... OK
Successfully installed ExtUtils-Config-0.007
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'ExtUtils::Config' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for ExtUtils-InstallPaths-0.010.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'TAP::Harness::Env' is not installed, Module 'ExtUtils::Helpers' is not installed, Module 'ExtUtils::InstallPaths' is not installed, Module 'ExtUtils::Config' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Module-Build-Tiny-0.036.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Module::Build::Tiny' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Devel-REPL-1.003025.
3 distributions installed
```

Output of sw_vers:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F1066
```

Comment: Could you edit in the question what version of OS X you run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## perlbrew

You will find installing a local copy of `perl`, separate from the one bundled with Mac OS X, will make your module installation easier.

Use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) to install and manage a specific version of perl. This isolates your perl from OS X updates and changes which have [caused](http://perlnews.org/2011/04/dealing-with-xcode-4-and-cpan-breakage/) multiple [problems](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/02/16/apple_update_perl_breakage/) in the past:

```
curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
perlbrew install perl-5.16.0
perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
```

### cpan minus

On your isolated copy, install [cpan minus](http://cpanmin.us) to reduce the memory cost of installing modules:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

### Re-install Devel::REPL

With this done, try re-installing `Devel::REPL` using [cpanm](http://cpanmin.us):

```
cpanm Devel::REPL
```

...or cpan:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Devel::REPL'
```

You should find modules install with less problems and are no longer affected by system updates or changes in Apple's decisions towards perl on OS X.

Comment: +1 to installing your own, local copy of Perl. This, in the long run, is much saner than doing `sudo cpanm ...` as you'll control when and if Perl changes on your machine, not Apple's OS updates. If you're already using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) you can install a local perl via it as well.